# Unable to use react router Link inside a simple nav tag

Tags: reactjs, react-router, tailwind-css, react-router-dom

```
import React from 'react'
import logo from './img/logo1.png'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Navbar() {
    return (
        <div>
 
            {/* theme switch and login signup */}
            <div className="border-2 border-blue-600 h-full">
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried wrapping around a normal div or a section at first, but didnt get a output. It was a fully blank white screen. I've done Link projects before and yet this is my first time encountering this problm. I have disabled reacts safe mode as well. What exactly should i do?

Comment: I don't see any overt issue in the specific code you shared here, so perhaps the issue is elsewhere. Are you saying *only* the `Navbar` renders blank. Where is `Navbar` rendered? Or the `Navbar` is rendered and the routes are not working? Please [edit] to clarify the exact specific problem and to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with that produces the issue.

Answer (score -1):

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './img/logo1.png';
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'; // Import BrowserRouter

export default function Navbar() {
    return (
        <Router> {/* Wrap your Link components inside Router */}
            <div>
                {/* theme switch and login signup */}
                <div className="border-2 border-blue-600 h-full">
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Router> {/* Close Router */}
    );
}
```